# How can i align Snackbar?

Tags: angular, css, angular-material2

I created Snackbar using material 2(below i have added demo) .I have one button in main page when i click that button it showing message(snackbar) in bottom of the page . i want to change this(snackbar message) into top right corner of the page. how can i do this ?? need help

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mbgkfv-gwjok6?file=app/snack-bar-component-example.ts)

Html

```
<button mat-button (click)="openSnackBar()" aria-label="Show an example snack-bar">
  Pizza party
</button>
```

component.ts

```
export class SnackBarComponentExample {

  constructor(public snackBar: MatSnackBar) {}

  openSnackBar(message="DOne", action = '') {
          this.snackBar.open(message, action, {
          duration: 5000,

        });
  }
}
```

Comment: As a warning: spamming comments asking people to answer your question is an abuse of the comment facility. These comments have been removed. Please don't do this again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is some updated CSS which will help you to show snack bar on the top left.

for more effect have a look [here](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/cdk/overlay/_overlay.scss)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mbgkfv-amqfpy?file=styles.css

here is your updated stackblitz which will reload the page after 5s.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mbgkfv-nc6bk6?file=app/snack-bar-component-example.ts

Comment: have a look here updated one https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mbgkfv-nc6bk6?file=app/snack-bar-component-example.ts

Comment: i want  snackbar to open right top corner if i add that css dialog box also coming top right corner .   https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z4tjwe-58bfsk?file=styles.css

Comment: i added rigt align css . when i click button snackbar coming top right corner but i have Dialog also on that same page. that dialog also coming top right..can you pls check the above link you came to know. my expectation dialog should come middle of the page snackbar should come top right corner of the page

Comment: don't worry brother here is updated stack https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z4tjwe-mjhkep?file=app/dialog-overview-example.ts

Comment: is it possible to change snackbar background color ??

Comment: here is the updated code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mbgkfv-vmmfvi?file=app/snack-bar-component-example.ts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164163/discussion-between-its-me-and-hrishikesh-kale).

Comment: IS it possible to align popup Add and cancel button right(align) side of the dialogue .https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z4tjwe-ddj2aw?file=app/dialog-overview-example.ts

Comment: @itsme Don't use hacky CSS, just specify it with the `verticalPosition` and `horizontalPosition` properties of `MatSnackBarConfig`

Answer (score 11):

An alternative way to do it is by specifying the `verticalPosition` and `horizontalPosition` configuration options of `MatSnackBarConfig`, which is passed via the `config` argument in `MatSnackBar#open`.

Here's an example:

```ts
openSnackBar(message: string, action?: string) {
    this.snackbar.open(message, action ? action : undefined, {verticalPosition: 'top', horizontalPosition: 'end'});
}
```

From the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/api#MatSnackBarConfig), only two values for the `verticalPosition` are allowed: `'top'` and `'bottom'`.

For `horizontalPosition`, `'start'`, `'center'`, `'end'`, `'left'` and `'right'`.

Here's an [updated demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/snackbar-top-so)

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```js
export class SnackBarComponentExample {

  constructor(public snackBar: MatSnackBar) {}

  openSnackBar(message="Done", action = '') {
          this.snackBar.open(message, action, {
          duration: 5000,
          verticalPosition: 'top',
          horizontalPosition:'right',
        });
  }
}
```

it worked for me .

Answer (score -1):

To add the snackbar in the top left corner add the following style in your global styles.css page

```
.cdk-global-overlay-wrapper {
  align-items: flex-start !important;
  justify-content: flex-start !important
}
```

And for top right

```
.cdk-global-overlay-wrapper {
  align-items: flex-start !important;
  justify-content: flex-end !important
}
```

Comment: Not able to get your question

Comment: Nope. Don't use hacky CSS. You can do it programmatically.